# Реализовать дружественные классы (friend class) в C#

Tags: c#, c++

Возможно ли как-нибудь реализовать функциональность в C#, как в C++ - "friend class" ?

Comment: функциональность дружественных классов неоднократно критиковалась и даже признавалась ошибочной многими специалистами. Зачем вам это нужно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прямого аналога нет.

Однако, если вам нужен доступ к `internal`-методам класса из другой сборки для тестирования, вам пригодится директива [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx).

---

Если вам нужен friend для чего-нибудь другого, возможно, у вас ошибочный дизайн. Чего именно вы хотите добиться?

---

Обновление: Для сценария, описанного в комментариях, попробуйте так:

1. Поместите серверный и клиентский код в разные сборки (они там и так должны быть, очевидно)
2. Заведите у сервера internal-интерфейс для модификации и public-интерфейс для чтения
3. Выдайте клиенту объект через интерфейс для чтения. Интерфейс для записи ему не доступен даже через прямой cast, ибо он является internal в другой сборке.

Код:

(Сервер:)

```
public interface IPlayer
{
    string CurrentTitle { get; }
    TimeSpan CurrentDuration { get; }
    // ...
}

internal interface IModifiablePlayer : IPlayer
{
    string CurrentTitle { get; set; }
    TimeSpan CurrentDuration { get; set; }
    // ...
}

class Player : IPlayer, IModifiablePlayer
{
    // имплементация
    public string CurrentTitle { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan CurrentDuration { get; set; }
}

public static class PlayerFactory
{
    static public IPlayer GetPlayer()
    {
        var player = new Player(); // решение о конкретном типе создаваемого
                                   // плейера может быть принято в этой точке.
                                   // гуглите IoC-контейнеры
        Init(player);
        return player;
    }

    static void Init(IModifiablePlayer player)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

(Клиент)

```
IPlayer player = Server.PlayerFactory.GetPlayer();
// (IModifiablePlayer)player не скомпилируется
```

Comment: я думал так: реализовал класс сервера. Клиентский код обращается к серверу, чтобы он его зарегистрировал. Сервер после регистрации возвращает обьект типа Player со свойствами только для чтения. Тоесть, клиентский код должен, только читать значения, а сервер имеет права модифицировать private поля выданого об'екта. Вспомнил с++, что эту задачу можно реализовать с помощью friend class

Comment: @nullptr: обновил ответ.

Comment: Немного подумав, я придумал ещё кое-что: думаю, паттерн Заместитель отлично подошел бы к этой задаче ? Сам Player был бы открыт для изменения, а только для чтения данные могли бы предоставлятся заместителем, который бы контролировал доступ к обьекту

Comment: @nullptr: Угу, так тоже покатило бы. Можно не давать наружу настоящий Player, только обёртку.

(ЗЫ: Слово «Заместитель» в роли «Proxy» смотрится непривычно.)